# Java applet game design no keyboard focus

Tags: java, architecture, input

`THIS IS PROBABLY THE WRONG PLACE. POSTED IT`[`HERE (STACKOVERFLOW)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122286/java-applet-game-design-keyboard-focus)

I'm making an applet game and it is rendering, the game loop is running, the animations are updating, but the keyboard input is not working. Here's an SSCCE.

```
public class Game extends JApplet implements Runnable {

    public void init(){
        // Initialize the game when called by browser
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        requestFocusInWindow();  // Always returning false
        GInput.install(this);    // Install the input manager for this class
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run(){
        startGameLoop();
    }

}
```

And Here's the GInput class.

```
public class GInput implements KeyListener {

    public static void install(Component c){
        new GInput(c);
    }

    public GInput(Component c){
        c.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("A key has been pressed");
    }

    ......

}
```

This is my GInput class. When run as an applet, it doesn't work and when I add the Game class to a frame, it works properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding [`Component.processKeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processKeyEvent%28java.awt.event.KeyEvent%29) in the Applet class. Also you may need to call `enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);` in the initialization. I have not tested this with Applets, but generally this has been the most robust way of handling keyboard in Java that I am aware of.

Comment: Sorry but I've found a solution for this in stack overflow. I've also posted the link in the post

Comment: It would still be nice to know if this solution worked for the question you asked

Answer (score 0):

Specify what key should be pressed to print your message.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
       System.out.println("A key has been pressed");
}
```

Comment: But it's not working for any key. I wan't to print it for any key

Comment: "A key has been pressed" ha.